# Theorem about Poincaré algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, poincare-duality

I read about Cohomology ring of finite-dimensional Grassmanian, and author used algebraic lemma as "every algebraist know about it, it is very easy". I've tried to prove it myself, search through the Internet, ask a few algebraist from my faculty, but they don't know about this statement. 
Lemma is the following:
Let $\mathbb{k}[x_1,\dots,x_m]$ be a polynomial ring over a field, $\deg x_i = d_i$. Let $\theta_1, \dots, \theta_m$ be homogeneous elements of degree $\deg\theta_i = s_i$ such that $\mathbb{k}[x_1,\dots,x_m]/(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_m)$ is finite dimensional vector space. Then $\mathbb{k}[x_1,\dots,x_m]/(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_m)$ is Poincaré algebra of formal dimension $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}(s_i-d_i)$.
(author uses definition of Poincaré algebra of formal dimension $d$ for graded algebra, such that it has exactly $d$ nonzero homogeneous components, $d$-th component is one-dimensional and there is non-degenerate pairing similar to  Poincaré duality in topology).

Actually, I think I can prove fact about dimension using Poincaré series and Koszul resolution, but how can I prove the last facts?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which author? Link? Page?

Comment: It is from lecture notes of old topology course  of A.A. Aisenberg at Independent University of Moscow. It is written in Russian, there is no Link to English version. But there is no extra information about Poincare algebras in notes.

Comment: Can you do this when $d_i=1$ for all $i$ first? May be even assuming $\theta_i=x_i^{s_i}$ for all $i$?